# Get callback from a url loading inside webview

Tags: java, android, url, webview

I am loading an Url from that page, we do some action and redirect to a New page inside WebView. now I want to get Callback when redirected page finishes loading.

I have tried

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                L.d(url);
                if (url.contains("Thank-you")) {
                    Utility.showToast(TabsActivity.this, "Subscription Done");
                }
            }
```

and also override

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        L.d(url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

but I am still not able to get the callback from URL.

Comment: whats is your url?

Answer (score 0):

a bit of guessing is needed here, but I still believe, that you are try to find the string "Thank-you" in the url, but the url is written in lower case. Also you could try using [WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) and then the [onProgressChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView,%20int)) method.

Regards Tarik.

Answer (score 0):

Register WebViewClient on your webview to return page finish listerner like this:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```